# Deploy a Self Hosted WCF Service with TFS 2010 Build?

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a console app that runs a self hosted WCF Data Service.

I have it auto building just fine.  But now I want to take the latest build and move it to my Dev Machine and run it.

Something like this:

1. Run the Build
2. Kill the existing running exe (if it is running)
3. Copy the new files over the old ones
4. Run the new exe.

Is this something I am going to have to put together by hand?  Are there tasks that are already done that may help with this?

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sounds like you need a regular batch file called as a post-build step that:

1. kills the running WCF host (using [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) for example)
2. Copies the new file to the destination location using (X)Copy
3. Start the new exe using the Start command

If to be performed on a build server, make sure you have a workflow activity inserted after the build step that allows you to start such a batch file (like the [InvokeProcess](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/a1bf2075-f176-4fba-8d33-db4de033f86c/) activity)

Or am I overseeeing some complexity here?

Comment: I was hoping for a plug and play solution, but I think this will work best.  Thanks!